# Show that u is harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

$\Omega$ simply connected region and $u$ is continuous on $\overline\Omega$. $u$ fulfill the mean value propery for every ball $B(x,r)$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subset \Omega$

$u(x)=\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)\ d\sigma(y)$

Prove u is harmonic

Hint: Assume $\Delta u \neq0$ in some ball $B(a,R)\subset \Omega $ consider auxiliary function $v$ wich solves the boundary condition

$-\Delta v=0 \ $in $B(a,R)$

$v=0 $on $\partial B(a,R)$ and use it appropriately

I don't know how to use the Hint, Can someone help me please

Comment: You said $u$ is continuous, so $\Delta u$ does not necessarily exist. Are you allowed to assume $u\in C^2$? The result is true either way but much easier when $u\in C^2$.

Comment: @Jeff I don't know. It doesn't say anything in the question but can you give me a clue how to solve in both cases and how I have to use the Hint

Comment: You should have $v=u$ on $\partial B$ (that is a mistake I believe). Then show that $w=u-v$ satisfies the mean value property for every ball, and hence $w$ satisfies the maximum principle and $w=0$ on $\partial B$. This implies $w=0$ and $u=v$, so $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: @Jeff, sorry you are right. Thanks